# How does a moving charge produce a magnetic field? In AC, charges are accelerating but they are possessing magnetic field also

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am unable to understand that how the moving charge produces magnetic field around itself. Some one has answered that any moving charge is without acceleration due to which it produce electric and magnetic field. I am confused that electric field is possessed by charge when it is in rest as well. Why does it  not posses magnetic field?